# How do I set the origin in the DeepL API on javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deepl

What else should I try?

I'm currently sending a request to the DeepL API in axios, but I'm getting a 403 response due to a CORS issue.

And tried to set the option using querystring as shown here, but it didn't work. https://github.com/funkyremi/deepl/blob/master/index.ts
Also, using the library at the URL above returns 403.

Furthermore, there is no origin setting in the account settings of DeepL.

I tried using 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' for axios headers: {}, and I also tried setting options for params: { } and not using querystring, but they didn't work.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import querystring from 'querystring';

export const translateDeepL = async() => {
  const options = {
      "auth_key": process.env.DEEPL_AUTH_KEY,
      "text": 'everyday is birthday.',
      "target_lang": 'JA',
  };
  const url = "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate";
  const data = await axios.post(url, querystring.stringify(options)).then(r => r);
  console.log(data);
}
```

```
VM3451:1 POST https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate 403
```

the request use https with ngrok did't work also.

I also tried the GET method for "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/usage" but got the same result.

It is definitely api-free.deepl.com since I am using the free plan.

By the way, the above code is executed as a component in React.

Comment: This is an example of a re-quest from the official website.


POST /v2/translate?auth_key=myapikey> HTTP/1.0

Host: api-free.deepl.com

User-Agent: YourApp

Accept: */*

Content-Length: [length]

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

auth_key=myapikey&text=Hello, world&target_lang=DE

Comment: By any chance, were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

the DeepL API does not support being used directly from within browser-based apps. The API Key is not supposed to be shared publicly as well and should always be kept secret.

The best approach is to use a backend proxy for the API Calls.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering this same issue and couldn't find an answer. This API just didn't seem to want to talk to me via a browser.

My 'solution' was to set up an API proxy in node.

It works fine fetching from a back-end + now I can add some rate limiting etc

C.J on [coding garden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCWE6eonL7k) can explain this way better than I ever can.

Answer (score 0):

You might be being blocked because of sending a request from http (your localhost) to https, try using the proxy axios config, like

```
const response = await axios
.get("https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate", {
  params: {
    auth_key: x,
    text: y,
    target_lang: z
  },
  proxy: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080
  }
});
```

return response;
};